# Identical code using more than double the RAM memory on different computers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory

I'm creating a Minecraft clone in C++ with OpenGL.

I noticed today that when debugging the program on my laptop, the RAM usage is **way** higher that the RAM usage on my desktop PC (~1.3gb vs ~500mb). I'm getting these memory numbers from Visual Studio's diagnostics tools.

I'm using GitHub and even with the same branch, same commit, literally the exact same code, the laptop uses more RAM. I tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, cloning again, nothing works.

The memory usage is different on the Windows Task Manager, too.

I'm out of ideas of what could be happening. The computers are on different platforms (laptop is Intel 10th, and desktop is Ryzen 3000), the laptop has less RAM (8gb vs 16gb). Both are using the latest Windows 10. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019.

I'm not sure if a platform difference could cause such a huge impact on memory allocation.

Comment: Is it possible that you're running the application with the debug flags enabled on the laptop, but not the desktop?

Comment: Are you maybe compiling one in x86 mode and the other x64?  That *could* make some types double in size.

Comment: I'm going to put my money on the laptop using unified memory. In other words, the GPU memory usage  is getting reported as RAM. If that's the case, the GPU memory usage on the desktop should roughly match the difference (assuming both are running at the same resolution).

Comment: I edited the comment above to be more clear, booth of the computers are running with release x64 on visual studio's selection that is on the side of the run button.

Comment: @Frank probably figured it out. I'm going to make some more tests to confirm.

Comment: If you have a GL resource leak in your app, different drivers will handle it differently. Are you checking for all GL errors & logging them *correctly*? (Also, this sounds a lot like a Guildhall assignment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many laptop architectures use something called *unified memory*. That is to say, there is only one big pool of memory that is shared between the CPU and GPU (or the equivalent portions on an APU).

On such architectures, allocating video memory is essentially the same thing as allocating RAM. It's all hidden away by the graphics drivers though.

So a graphics-heavy application using more RAM on a laptop than on a desktop with a discrete GPU is not surprising. However, it's not so much that it uses more memory, just that the memory it uses gets tabulated differently.

Assuming both platforms run at the same resolution and the same assets are loaded, you'd expect `GPU Memory + RAM` usage on desktop would be roughly equivalent to `RAM` usage on the laptop.

Emphasis on the word *roughly*. Different graphic architectures/drivers use memory differently, so don't expect a 1-to-1 match here. For example:

- A single 1080p framebuffer takes a few megabytes at the minimum, depending on how the driver interacts with the actual screen, how many of these are around is rarely obvious.
- Tiled architectures can completely bypass needing large chunks of
  memory altogether.

That's the most likely scenario here.

Comment: I forced my laptop to use the discrete GPU over the iGPU and the RAM usage almost matched the expected. I didn't expect it to use my iGPU even though it is an 3d application. Spot on :)